# How to positioning control buttons outside controlbar in video.js

Tags: javascript, media-player, video.js

Is there a given possibility to style the controls outside of the controlbar?

Currently the control buttons are inside of the control bar-container but i want to use free positions for every button.

Is there a setting for that or do i just have to place them outside the bar with some js code?

Here is an example how i would like to place the buttons
[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUPRb.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can a component directly to the player with e.g. `player.addChild('PlayToggle', {})`.

You'll find the list of standard control components at https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-components.html

Comment: Thanks. Should i disable the controlbar then?

Comment: You can do that with `{"controlBar": false}` as a player setup option